# issues while taking aws es snapshot for each indices using python script

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-curator

I am trying to extend/modify python script for taking aws elasticsearch snapshots.

I want to take a snapshot of each index into a S3 bucket before deleting it. Below is the script that I have so far.

issue: when I execute this it is creating a snapshot with all the indices where as I want to create one snapshot for one indices.

result: each indices should have a successful snapshot and upon which it has to be deleted.

```js
import boto3
import requests
import json
from requests_aws4auth import AWS4Auth
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch, RequestsHttpConnection
import curator

host = 'search-xx-xxxxxas-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxxxx.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com' # For example, search-my-domain.region.es.amazonaws.com
region = 'us-east-1' # For example, us-west-1
service = 'es'
credentials = boto3.Session().get_credentials()
awsauth = AWS4Auth(credentials.access_key, credentials.secret_key, region, service, session_token=credentials.token)
TRUE = 'true'
FALSE = 'false'

# Build the Elasticsearch client.
es = Elasticsearch(
    hosts = [{'host': host, 'port': 443}],
    http_auth = awsauth,
    use_ssl = True,
    verify_certs = True,
    connection_class = RequestsHttpConnection
)

index_list = curator.IndexList(es)

# Filters by age, anything with a time stamp older than 30 days in the index name.
index_list.filter_by_age(source='name', direction='older', timestring='%Y.%m.%d', unit='days', unit_count=67)
print("Found %s indices to delete" % len(index_list.indices))

## Creating snapshots for the above.
for x in range(len(index_list.indices)):
    index = index_list.indices[x]
    print(type(index))
    url = 'https://'+host+'/_snapshot/qc-snapshots/'+ index
    payload_dict = { 
        "indices": index,
        "ignore_unavailable": True ,
        "include_global_state": False
        }
    payload = json.dumps(payload_dict)
    headers = {
    'Content-Type': "application/json",
    'Cache-Control': "no-cache"
    }

    print(url)
    print(payload)
    print(headers)
    r = requests.put(url, auth=awsauth, json=payload, headers=headers)
    print(r.status_code)
    print(r.text)
```

Comment: Why do you want one snapshot per index? That's not optimal for snapshots in Elasticsearch. Elasticsearch permits you to restore one index at a time from a snapshot, so there's no need to have one snapshot per index. 

This is also a bad idea because Elasticsearch freezes the segments during each snapshot, which puts strain on the other segments and background merging while this is going on. It's better practice to lump them together and restore individually.

Comment: thanks a lot for your suggestion.. all of the sudden curator module itself has stopped working. I have raised a new question regarding this. https://stackoverflow.com/q/54905788/11114306